# Tikz : Draw a double bicolor line on a partial rectiligne path

Tags: tikz-pgf

I try to draw a bicolor line (only a part of a rectiligne path).

It works for horizontal lines, but obviously what I did can't work for oblique or verticale line.

Is it possible ? As a tikzstyle would be great.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (A) at (-1,0) ;
\coordinate (B) at (1,0) ;
\coordinate (C) at ($(A)!.55!(B)$) ;

\draw[thick,red,transform canvas={yshift=.5\pgflinewidth}] (A)--(C) ;
\draw[thick,blue,transform canvas={yshift=-.5\pgflinewidth}] (A)--(B) ;

\coordinate (B) at (1,2) ;
\coordinate (C) at ($(A)!.55!(B)$) ;

\draw[thick,red,transform canvas={yshift=.5\pgflinewidth}] (A)--(C) ;
\draw[thick,blue,transform canvas={yshift=-.5\pgflinewidth}] (A)--(B) ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Solved here :http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261374/tikz-decorations-markings-marks-location-problem/261378?noredirect=1#comment626603_261378