# Tikz - decorations.markings marks location problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations, tikzmark

Why blue and red lines don't fit the black line, and why are they overlap each other ?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[Dble/.style args={#1 and #2}{%
decoration={%
    markings,% switch on markings
    mark=at position 0 with {%
        \node[yshift= .5\pgflinewidth] (Axx) {};
        \node[yshift=-.5\pgflinewidth] (Bxx) {};},
    mark=at position 1 with {%
        \node[yshift= .5\pgflinewidth] (Ayy) {};
        \node[yshift=-.5\pgflinewidth] (Byy) {};
        \draw [#1] (Axx)--(Ayy) ;
        \draw [#2] (Bxx)--(Byy) ;}
    },
    postaction={decorate}}
]

\coordinate (A) at (0,0) ;
\coordinate (B) at (1,1) ;

\draw[Dble={blue and red},very thick] (A)--(B) ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't that expected? You're shifting only in the y-direction, not perpendicular to the line.

Comment: The length problem is solved by using coodinate instead of node, sully of my.

Comment: In a markings environment, there is a new coordinate system see p. 592-593 and y-axis should be perpendicular to the path.

Comment: I don't think you have the same version of `pgfmanual.pdf` as me, on p. 593 I find the *Entity-Relationship Diagram Drawing Library*.

Comment: I have the 3.0.0 comming with texlive 2015.

Comment: But I think you were looking at pages 572-573.

Comment: The mystery is full, look at the image in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[Dble/.style args={#1 and #2}{%
decoration={%
    markings,% switch on markings
    mark=at position 0 with {%
        \coordinate (Axx) at (0,.5\pgflinewidth);%
        \coordinate (Bxx) at (0,-.5\pgflinewidth);},%
    mark=at position 1 with {%
        \coordinate (Ayy) at (0,.5\pgflinewidth);%
        \coordinate (Byy) at (0,-.5\pgflinewidth);%
        \draw [#1] (Axx)--(Ayy) ;%
        \draw [#2] (Bxx)--(Byy) ;}%
    },%
    postaction={decorate}}
]

\coordinate (A) at (0,0) node {A};
\coordinate (B) at (1,1) ;

\path[Dble={blue and red},very thick] (A)--(B) ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```